# Cannot add rows to datagridview Dynamically

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Columns.Add("name1", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("name2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("name3", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("name4", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("name5", typeof(string));
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    try
    {
        dr[i] = dt.Rows.Add();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return;
    }
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

I'm getting error: "Cannot find column 5". If I will change `i < 6` to `i < 5`, everything works fine. How to add more than 5 rows? Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to add rows to datatable.

Comment: First you sould add column. Then add rows. For example: `dt.Columns.Add("C1"); dt.Columns.Add("C1"); dr.Rows.Add("a", "aa");dr.Rows.Add("b", "bb");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("name1", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("name2", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("name3", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("name4", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("name5", typeof(string));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            dt.Rows.Add("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out.